# Uniform Convergence and Poles

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions holomorphic on a deleted neighborhood $N_0(w,r)$ of $w$. Let $(f_n)$ converge uniformly to $f$ on every compact $K \subseteq N_0(w,r)$. If each $f_n$ has a pole at $w$, does $f$ have a pole at $w$?

My attempt:

The statement is true.

Since $\lim_{z \to w}  f_n(z) = \infty$, then

$\lim_{z \to w} f(z) = \lim_{z \to w} (\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(z)) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (\lim_{z \to w}  f_n(z)) = \infty$

Would that be correct?

Comment: But each compact $K$ stays away from $w$. Consider $w = 0$, $f_n(z) = \frac{1}{nz}$.

Comment: In this counterexample, does $(f_n)$ converge uniformly to $f(z) = 0$?

Comment: Uniformly on compact subsets of $N_0(0,r)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel Fischer wrote, the answer is negative: $f$ need not have a pole at $w$. For every function $g$ holomorphic in a domain $U$, the sequence $f_n(z)=g(z)/n$ converges to $0$ uniformly on compact subsets of $U$. Indeed, $g$ is bounded on compact sets, which leads to $\sup_K |f_n| = n^{-1} \sup_K |g|\to 0$. Choosing $g(z)=1/z$ on $U=\{z: 0<|z|<1\}$ leads to a counterexample.

Under the much stronger assumption "$f_n\to f$ uniformly on $N_0(w,r)$", the conclusion is true. Indeed, if $f_n$ has a pole at $w$ and $f-f_n$ is bounded on  $N_0(w,r)$, then $f$ also has a pole at $w$, because the singularity of $f-f_n$ at $w$ is removable.