# What means the notation $N_0(\omega,r)$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, notation

In the post [Uniform Convergence and Poles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555555/uniform-convergence-and-poles) the authors use the notation $N_0(\omega,r)$. I do not know what it means, so I can not take advantage of the presented answers. Can anyone tell me what the notation means?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It means $N_0(w,r) = \{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z-w|<r , z\ne w \}$ which is equal to the open ball without it is center.

Comment: Thank you. (I wonder why there is a $0$ in subscript though...)

Comment: it is a notation